# Post-install of CDH on EC2 using Cloudera Manager -- can't locate 'hadoop' executable to use hdfs

Tags: cloudera

I've successfully installed a hadoop cluster on EC2 using Cloudera Manager.  All the services are up and running.

Now I wish to use the command line client to add files to hdfs.  I've ssh'd into the server and there is no such executable that I can find.  I'm assuming I've overlooking something simple.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

CDH should setup an alias to access hadoop, if not you can find all the hadoop ecosystem projects under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib

The binary for hadoop is:
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop